# Easy problem involving joint probability distributions

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1$ denote time time (hr) it takes to perform a first tast and $X_2$ denote the time it takes to perform a second one. The second task always takes at least as long to perform as the first task. The joint pdf of these variables is $f(x_1,x_2) = 2(x_1+x_2)$ when $0 \leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq 1$, and zero otherwise.

a) Obtain the pdf of the total completion time for two task.

b) Obtain the pdf of the difference $X_2-X_1$ between the longer completion time and the shorter time.

My best try:

When I did $U = X_1+X_2$ and $V=X_2-X_1$ i got the new joint function $f(u,v)=u$, from which the answers for the a)-part were $\int_0^u{u}dv=u^2$ and $\int_u^2{u}dv=2u-u^2$. It it the b)-part i dont seem to grasp.

Why shoudnt the answer for b) just be $\int_0^v{u}du=\frac{1}{2}v^2$? Or at least be an integral on the form $\int_a^b{u}du$? However, I see that $f(u,v)$ dont depend upon $v$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the support of the joint density of $U$ and $V$.

$U = X_2 + X_1, V = X_2 - X_1, 0 \le x_1 \le x_2 \le 1$

$f_{UV}(u, v) = u~$ and the support of the joint distribution can be written as,

$\left
\{\begin{array}
{l}0 \le v \le u, 0 \le u \le 1 \\ 0 \le v \le 2 - u, 1 \le u \le 2
\end{array}
\right.$

OR

$v \leq u \leq 2 - v, 0 \leq v \leq 1$

$a)$ The pdf of $U$ is,

$ \displaystyle f_U(u) = \int_0^u u ~ dv = u^2, ~0 \leq u \leq 1$

$ \displaystyle f_U(u) = \int_0^{2-u} u ~ dv = 2u - u^2, ~1 \leq u \leq 2$

$b)$ For the pdf of $V$,

$ \displaystyle f_V(v) = \int_v^{2-v} u ~ du = 2 (1 - v), ~ 0 \leq v \leq 1$

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was the limits for integration that were the issue..

Answer (score 0):

You have $0\le V\le U$ and $0 <V \le 2-U$, which you recognised in the integral range  $\int\limits_0^u{u}\,dv=u^2$   when $0 \le u \le 1$.

But when $1 \le u \le 2$, you should have had $\int\limits_0^{2-u} u\, dv =2u-u^2$ and you were lucky that your error in the interval still produced the correct answer.

Now looking at the marginal density for $V$ you have $V\le U \le 2-V$ and so $$\int\limits_v^{2-v} u\, du =2-2v$$ at least when $0\le v \le 1$.